# How to parse specific XML tags

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

Currently, I have been parsing simple tags, but I cant figure out how to do the more complicated and duplicated tags...

Code Example Ive been doing:

```
while (xpp.getEventType()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (xpp.getEventType()==XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
            weatherDetails.setWeatherLocation(xpp.nextText());
            weather_userlocation.setText(weatherDetails.getWeatherLocation());
        }
    }
```

So I can single out the  tag because their is only one... but what if there are multiple:

```
-<weather time-layout="k-p12h-n14-1">
    <name>Weather Type, Coverage, Intensity</name>
       <weather-conditions weather-summary="Mostly Cloudy"/>
       <weather-conditions weather-summary="Rainy"/>
</weather>
```

I want to select the first weather condition and get that text "Mostly Cloudy".
How can I single specific tags out that are duplicated?

Thanks c:

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/). You don't have to deal with writing your own parser.